# How to do click() command with python but on "tableau"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tableau-api

I'm really new to python, but I was able to do this kind of downloading files from a website :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get("http://www.yeastgenome.org/locus/S000001142/overview")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 4)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/section[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/a"))).click()

for i in range(1,5):
    i = str(i)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/section[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li["+i+"]/a"))).click()
```

it works for me, downloaded those file.

the thing is I learnt that you need to inspect element from website to do click(), but in tableau, i can't do select elemetn. How to do it? THanks.

Comment: this tableau website provides pdf to be downloaded, so I want to do click on that download button, but no luck, no inspect element at all.

Comment: using selenium to automate click on the tableau server might be challenging. You also need to consider to log in when your session is out

Answer (score 1):

Embedded Tableau workbooks are all placed inside of an `iframe` so you can't single out and click on items within that frame. You can navigate to another url that will give you a pdf and then use selenium from there.

All you need to do is add `.pdf` to the end of the url you are trying to access and you will get a pdf version of the workbook in the browser.

`http://<servername>/#/views/<workbook>/sheet?:iid=7`

will become

`http://<servername>/#/views/<workbook>/sheet.pdf`

Then look for the download element (`id="download"`) and click it with selenium.

[image: download element]

See this kb from Tableau for more detail.

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/link_view.htm